# FIle download via cmd in windows using HTML

Tags: javascript, html, windows, cmd, download

I trying to download certain data from a site from cmd of windows. When I am downloading via this method, it is generating a firefox window and a pop up which I do not want. I should be downloaded to desired folder in background. 
I have created an index.HTML file in a directory.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <script>
 window.location.href = 'http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_gfs_0p50.pl?file=gfs.t06z.pgrb2full.0p50.f000&lev_10_m_above_ground=on&var_UGRD=on&var_VGRD=on&subregion=&leftlon=80.6&rightlon=85.4&toplat=25.6&bottomlat=20.1&dir=%2Fgfs.2015060606' ;
</script>
</html>
```

At cmd I am doing this "start index.HTML"

It is generating a firefox window and save popup which is asking for save permission. Is there any way I can do that more smoothly in the background.So that the window doesn't come.

Comment: You should use `curl` or `wget`.

Comment: wget is working just fine. That was a silly mistake of mine. I should have remember that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows and Internet Explorer, you can write a VBScript. 
It can be executed from the command line or just be embed in HTML documents.
You can search stack exchange for some useful VBScripts expamples.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not use PowerShell? I don't have access to a Windows machine at the moment, but this should work.

```
$localFile = "C:\Users\<Username>\Downloads\index.html"
$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$urlAddress = "http://example.com/index.html"
$webclient.DownloadFile($url,$localFile)
```

This will download the data that stored at `$urlAddress` and store it in `$localFile`.